# In Java to use tika... how to resolve 'java.io.IOException'

Tags: java, apache-tika

I am using tika with Java for crawling program. I have used BSF_Recursive for that. After some results, it shows me this...

http://www.google.com

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://translate.google.com/
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: `catch` it, do something you feel is appropriate. Also check why this happens. Google apparently considers whatever you do "Forbidden"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely a protection from DDOS attacks.

You can't do much about it. You can catch the exception but the processing will not continue.